# Import data from SharePoint to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure

We have migrated to DevOps from SharePoint 2010. We need to Import all the user stories we have in sharepoint to Azure DevOps . Can any one help me with a better way to go about this?

Know someone who can answer?

Answer (score 2):

There are no tools to import data from SharePoint to Azure DevOps. You can consider the following:

1. [Export SharePoint List to csv](https://techwizard.cloud/2016/06/20/export-sharepoint-list-to-csv/) and then [import it to Azure DevOps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops)
2. Use Excel integration. Export Sharepoint list to Excel and then copy/paste data to Excel linked with Azure DevOps and [publish it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process).